# How to apply different style to <ul> <li> and <a> tags in different menu

Tags: css, html

I want to apply style to top menu `<ul>`,`<li>` and `<a>` tags and different style to body menu  `<ul>`,`<li>` and `<a>` tags .

how it is possible.

in short i want different style for ul li and a tags for top menu and different style for ui li and a tags for body menu
code for top menu

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, its a css question. See "css <" for more information

Comment: Separate your top menu and body menu with different and unique ID or class. Then apply css.

Comment: Before asking, please consider trying it yourself first next time and include what you've tried so far in the question.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If an answer helped you with your issue please mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign classes or ids to the menus/items to distinguish them from each other and then style the classes/ids in the CSS. Example HTML:

```
<ul id="top-menu">
    <li>
        <a>Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="body-menu">
    <li>
        <a>Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul#top-menu {
    STYLES
}
#top-menu > li {
    STYLES
}
#top-menu > li > a {
    STYLES
}
ul.body-menu {
    STYLES
}
ul.body-menu > li {
    STYLES
}
ul.body-menu > li > a {
    STYLES
}
```